# Transferring photos from "Documents by Readdle" app to Camera Roll without uploading it to cloud or connecting to a PC?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud, photos

I have found that that the photos that I have added to the [Documents by Readdle app](https://apps.apple.com/app/documents-by-readdle/id364901807) are not visible to any other app on my iPad.

I recently installed a GIF maker app which is not able to find any photos that are not inside camera roll.

How do I make it see the photos in *Documents by Readdle* app without having to upload it to cloud or connecting iPad to my computer?

Comment: Are you talking about the Files app?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I am talking about `Documents by Readdle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documents by Readdle has a feature using which you can export images to Camera roll on your iPad. You can either export images individually, or select more than one images and export them all in one go.

To export a single image to your Camera roll, do the following:

1. Open the Documents app, locate the image you wish to export and tap on the options button (three blue dots) towards the bottom right of the image icon.

   [image]

2. Tapping on the options button will reveal the app's share context menu. Tap on the Share button.

   [image]

3. You'll be presented with iOS's share sheet. Tap on the Save Image button to export the image to the Camera roll.

   [image]

4. A copy of the image will be saved in the Camera roll and can be viewed in the Photos app. This image will be available to any app which is permitted to access Photos.

   [image]

---

To export multiple images to your Camera roll in one go, do the following:

1. Tap on the Select button in the toolbar at the top right and select the desired images.

   [image]

2. In the sidebar on the left, tap on the Share button to reveal the iOS's share sheet. Tap on Save x images to export them to the Camera roll in one go.

   [image]

Comment: Yup, that worked. Thanks Nimesh. Do you by any chance know how could I just directly transfer photos to Camera Roll from PC? It is rather redundant to transfer photos to 'Documents' and then gallery.

Comment: @Arbaaz I am assuming you are using a Windows PC. Install [iTunes for Windows](https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/), connect your iPad and you can transfer photos from your PC to iPad. They will show up in the Photos app on your iPad.

Comment: I don't recall seeing photos app in the list in iTunes on my windows PC. But I will recheck.

Comment: @Arbaaz Photos app is installed on iPad. In iTunes for Windows, it should show up as just Photos item in the sidebar on left side.

Comment: Nope could not find the app in the list under file sharing. And the icon under settings at the extreme left doesnt do anything

Comment: @Arbaaz I don't get it? What is the context here?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out that iCloud sync was turned on for photos which is why i did not see sync checkbox in itunes for photos. I have disabled icloud sync and now i can transfer photos using itunes