# Is there any free iOS video player that allows you to transfer and keep a folder hierarchy intact?

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation, video

I have a video course folder that in turn has multiple folders (one for each chapter). I was using VLC on my ipad and found out that when I copy the parent folder to the device, it just copies all the files to a folder. ie removing all sub folders and adding ALL the videos in just one parent folder.

I switched to infuse. Turns out you can have only 1 level of folder. ie. if you have a Parent Folder which has 10 sub folders. You will now have just 10 folders without parent. Also this app does not even have basic functionality as playing videos as faster speed.

Comment: Are you looking for ways to transfer/work with folders into VLC, for a video player which is aware of folders, or something else?

Comment: @nohillside I am looking for a video player (vlc or any) which is aware of folders

Comment: VLC automatically groups videos into folder based on the name, doesn‘t this work in your case?

Comment: @nohillside I think it doesnt let you sort videos by name. So if a folder has 20 videos .. you cant sort it name. So you will constantly be looking for next video in the video series.

Comment: It can :-) on the iPhone it’s the button with the arrows on top left, on the iPad probably similar

Comment: @nohillside Can you send a screenshot of button? (assuming its not a physical button)

Comment: Same place on the iPad: start VLC, select Videos in bottom row, there is a button with up/down arrow at top left. If you switch to "Video Groups" on top  and select one of the automatically created groups, the button for sorting within the group is on top right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [PlayerXtreme](https://playerxtreme.com/) on my iPhone and it's keeping all level folder, you should try it !

I've only be using the free version so far, but it does the job (and you can get more feature by giving them an availiation on the Appstore)

> On their website, they claim that :
>
> - **Files and Folders**: Dont need to learn the app. It is almost like using Windows or Mac OSX.
> - **Library Organization**: Organize all of your media-videos, photos, and music

Answer (score 1):

The best file storage tool is the native tool, so just put your files in folders in the files app on ios13.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206481

There’s no need for a player unless your videos use non-standard codec, and then start with VLC or a different player if you have such a large library that getting things encoded isn’t worth the time. Don’t even use VLC until you’re forced to. That being said, my Documents folder and dozens of music, video, pdf files all transfer perfectly from Mac to iCloud web interface to files on iPhone and iPad. VLC for iOS navigates this hierarchical storage perfectly so I’m guessing you are struggling to load your folders into VLC sandbox and not using the files app.

Putting [video files (or any files) in a specific app sandbox is really fighting against the grain](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363571/transferring-photos-from-documents-by-readdle-app-to-camera-roll-without-uploa).